# Как в iTerm при клике на строку скопировать ее в поле ввода

Tags: git, terminal

Подскажите какие клавиши зажать, а то тяжело все нужные мне файлы в гит добавлять ручками.

Comment: `все нужные мне файлы в гит добавлять` -- а почему не добавлять с ключом `-A` файлы? Вот так: `git add -A`, либо добавляйте по каталогу, указывая путь

Comment: дело в том, что где-то 1/3 файлов добавлять мне не надо, а так добавятся все как я понял

Comment: @Dunai, а откуда вы получаете список файлов, из которого хотите копировать нужные вам файлы?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вы полагаете, что есть файл со списком того, что нужно добавить и автоматизировать процесс? В принципе, если бы такой файл был, можно было бы быстро добавить именно их -- но мне кажется, что это у автора в голове представление, как нужно разделить коммит на несколько более мелких.

Comment: @AK, возможно, автор вопроса копирует из вывода `git status`. вот я и уточняю.

Comment: да, совершенно верно, из git status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляйте файлы по отдельным каталогам:

Было:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   calc/index.php
#       modified:   include/configs/keys.php
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Выполнили команду:

```
$ git add calc/
```

Стало:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   calc/index.php
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   include/configs/keys.php
#
$
```

Можете также использовать знак * чтобы указать часть имени файла и так далее.

Ещё можно занести все файлы скопом, а потом исключить (`unstage`) ненужные, если вы видите, что исключать меньше файлов, чем добавлять.

Было:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   calc/index.php
#       modified:   include/configs/keys.php
#
```

Выполнили команду:

```
$ git reset calc/
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       calc/index.php
```

Стало:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   include/configs/keys.php
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   calc/index.php
#
$
```